# Tinymce with FrameSet not working?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, frameset

i am using tinymce attached with Textarea in my project. It works great. But when text area is inside frameset, it does not work.
here is small code snippet of textarea inside frameset. It works as soon as i remove framesets(just remove the framset tags from below code snippet, it works). i am not getting what i am missing here

```
<html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
     <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></SCRIPT>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" ></script>
     <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
     appendTinyMCE();
    function appendTinyMCE(){
     tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "advlist",
         theme_advanced_buttons1 : "forecolor,backcolor,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,sub,sup,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true

});}


});
</script>
</head>
<frameset framespacing="0" border="1" frameborder="1" cols="50%,50%">
<frame scrolling="NO"  name="checkPanel">
</frame>
<frameset rows="18%,*">
<frame scrolling="NO" noresize="" src="about:blank" name="heading">
<frame id="spellBody" scrolling="NO" noresize="" src="about:blank" name="preview" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
<html>
<body>
<textarea style="width: 100%;" name="bodyTest" rows="20"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size=2><p>This is my Test Text</p><BR> <p> </p><BR> <p><strong>Thanks and Regards</strong></p><BR> <p><font color=blue><strong>Scott</strong></font> Miles</p></textarea>
</body>
</html>
</frame>
</frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

**I am not sure do i need to do some extra configuration to make tinymce work with Frameset? I am also fine if i can bind tinymce with frame instead of
textArea, if it is possible?**

Comment: Quickest solution is to move your javascript into the head of the Frameset HTML. `tinyMCE.init()` will work on all textareas in the current document, but the contents of a Frameset (or an iframe) are considered a different document, or at least have a different `document` object.

Comment: i tried moving  javascript(dom ready function) into the head of the Frameset HTML but dis not work too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickest solution is to move all your javascript into the head of the Frameset HTML. `tinyMCE.init()` will work on all textareas in the current document, but the contents of a Frameset (or an iframe) are considered a different document, or at least have a different `document` object.